# java.net.ConnectException: /192.168.1.106:8002 - Connection refused ( Android Exception )

Tags: java, android, sockets, socketexception

I am facing this current problem now.

I am able to send command to the device and receive response from the device from android emulator to the socket.

But, when I install the same application on tablet, there is a problem. The first time I send command to check status that device is connected or not, it send me the response that device is connected but when I send command second time it throws the following exception:

> java.net.ConnectException: /192.168.1.106:8002 - Connection refused.

This is the code that does the request:

```
public static String sendRequestandResponse(final String host,final int  port,
            final String command,
            final int timeoutInMillis,final int responseLength) throws UnknownHostException,NetworkSettingException

            {
        if (host == null)
        {
            throw new NullPointerException("host is null");  //NOPMD
        }
        Socket clientSocket=null;
        try {

            /**
             * Creating socket connection with IP address and port number to send Command
             */
            try{
                clientSocket = new Socket();

                SocketAddress remoteAdr = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
                clientSocket.connect(remoteAdr, 1000);
                clientSocket.setSoTimeout(timeoutInMillis);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new NetworkSettingException(e.getMessage());
            }




            final PrintWriter outPutStream = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), CHARSET));
            try
            {
                outPutStream.print(command);
                        outPutStream.flush();
                    BufferedReader responseString = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), CHARSET));
                response   = new StringBuilder(); 
                try
                {

                    int pos = 0;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        pos++;
                        System.out.println(pos);
                        int i=responseString.read();
                        byte[] resp={(byte)i};
                        System.out.println(new String(resp));
                        response.append(new String(resp));
                        if(pos>=responseLength){
                            {
                                clientSocket.shutdownInput();
                                clientSocket.shutdownOutput();
                                clientSocket.close();
                                Log.d("ConnectionSocket", "Socket closed with break");
                                break;
                            }


                        }
                    }

                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    responseString.close();
                }


            }
            finally
            {
                outPutStream.close();
            }

        }

        catch(IOException ex){
        }
        catch(NullPointerException ex){  //NOPMD
        }

        finally
        {
            try {
                clientSocket.shutdownInput();
                clientSocket.shutdownOutput();
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (NullPointerException ex) { //NOPMD
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }
        return response.toString();
            }
```

I think it doesnt close the socket first time, so second time it refuse the connection.

The same code works on emulator though.

Comment: make sure your tab can connect to the machine mentioned

Comment: "connection refused" means there is no server listening on the socket on the target host. Therefore, your client code is useless here.

Comment: as a sidenote... your exception handling is awful: http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#java-language-rules

Comment: Thanks guys, but tablet is on Wi-fi and what i observed is when i send command first time it works fine with tablet but second time it doesnt.. means it give Exception. might me the tablet is too fast then emulator. so it send command again before closing the socket and exception occur. i added sleep(1000) there before every write() and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the Connection Refused only when the server is not accepting the connection.

Mostly, the Problem is the Firewall which blocks the any untrusted incoming connection.

My application shows this message mostly when the server has a firewall which block it.

So u can add the Exception list in Firewall for your application.

Comment: FIrewalls cause connect timeouts, not refusals. A refusal would be an information leak to an attacker.